# Separate initials from full name input in python without using split

Tags: python, string, slice

*EDIT* This was my first post and I completely forgot to show what I had already tried. I wasn't looking for a complete program, just suggestions on methods I could use to concatenate initials. *EDIT*

I need to create a program that allows a user to input their full name and only prints the initials. This must be done **WITHOUT USING .SPLIT OR LISTS**

From my hw:
Write a program that gets a string of a person's full name – `first`, `middle`, and `last name` and then displays their initials.
 Create a function `getInitials()`.

```
>>>Enter your full name: James Tiberias Kirk
>>>J.T.K.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We can't do your homework. Technically, we can, but this won't help you understand the problem. Unless you have tried something and stumbled upon a problem that you couldn't fix yourself, we can't really help you. if you did try something, please post your efforts, what have you tried so far and where did you fail. After that, we can look at your code and fix your problem, but we can't write it all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming and this website so I didn't think to include what I tried. I appreciate your efforts to make sure I'm learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out thanks to all your responses. Our teacher wanted us to only use the narrow scope of what we've learned in class so there was pretty much only one way I would be allowed to write it. I ended up coming up with this:

```
def getInitials():
fullName=input("Enter your full name:")
initials=''
for ch in fullName:
    if ch.isupper():
        initials+=ch
        initials=str(initials)+"."
print (initials)

if __name__=="__getInitials__":
    getInitials()
getInitials()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
n = input('Enter your full name:')

name = ''
for i,j in enumerate(n):
    if i == 0:
        name+=(j+'.')
    elif j == ' ':
        name += (n[i+1]+'.')

print(name)
```

And this is as `method`:

```
def getinitials(n):
    name = ''
    for i,j in enumerate(n):
        if i == 0:
            name+=(j+'.')
        elif j == ' ':
            name += (n[i+1]+'.')
    return name

print(getinitials(input('Enter your number:')))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter your full name:James Tiberias Kirk
J.T.K.
```

Comment: This method was closest to what I needed to do. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If it is please accept is as the answer to your question, so others can find it easily and the question can have an accepted answer. Otherwise it looks like none is acceptable and the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you won't deal with names like DeFranco or McDonald, you can iterate over the string and append encountered capital letters (that is, `ord('A') <= ord(char) <= ord('Z')`) with a dot to your result.

Similar approach that should work on most cases is to append the first character, then look for spaces and append a character next to them.

Comment: This is out of the scope of what we've learned in class so far so I couldn't use it but I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

One solution that *technically* doesn't use a list:

```
'.'.join(i for i in x if i.isupper())+'.'
```

...which uses a generator expression, but that may be closer to a list than the spirit of the assignment. As in the other answer, it fails if a name has more than one capital in the name (McGregor, etc.)

Comment: Does not put a dot at the end: J.K.L.

Comment: Ready to go. Nice!!

Comment: Unfortunately our teacher wanted us to manipulate the strings very simply so this was out of scope. I appreciate the answer though!

Comment: I had a feeling, teachers don't generally like _technically_ following the rules

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, while returning a generator statement from your `getInitials()` function, therefore you technically avoid using both `split()` and a `list`:

```
import re

def getInitials(x):

    return '.'.join(i for i in re.findall(r'^[A-Z]|(?<=\s)[A-Z]', x)) + '.'

out = getInitials('James Tiberias Kirk McGregor')
```

Yields:

```
J.T.K.M.
```

Note that this method works for names with more than one capital letter per name/word.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response! This hasn't been covered in our class yet so I can't use it but I appreciate your input

Comment: I think because Paul Karahm, who commented on my initial post telling me that I can't ask people to do my work for me, was angry and wanted to discourage people trying to help me

Comment: And I didn't have enough influencer points or whatever to vote everyone's replies back up to 0

Comment: No worries at all, glad we could help and you were able to figure it out!